Calamares does not detect the NVMe
I have problems with the installation of the new Kubuntu 24.04. I tried to install from scratch Kubuntu 24.04 since I have the previous one installed on my HP laptop on a 512 GB NVMe, but Calamares does not detect the NVMe and I cannot start the installation. To rule out that it is the disk or some configuration in the BIOS I tried to install the same version I have installed before and it works perfectly and detects everything until the partitions I can see.
I also tried with other flavors of Ubuntu to see if it is only Kubuntu, but in all of them it is the same or it does not detect the NVMe or it detects it but not the partitions, as is the case of Ubuntu desktop and other flavors that have the new Subiquity installer.
In conclusion the flavors that I tried to install those that have Calamares as the installer do not detect the NVMe and in those that have the new installer detect it, but I cannot see any of the partitions.


Do you have latest firmware for UEFI & NVMe drive? Is drive correctly seen in UEFI/BIOS settings? What is now on drive? Does gparted see drive correctly, or post this from live installer: sudo parted -l Calmares worked with my desktop using NVMe drive.

Everything is correctly updated, the image I posted was directly from the installer, calamares works correctly with a previous version as I had expressed earlier specifically with 22.04 LTS, gparted detects the disk and partitions correctly.

Does gparted shows red or yellow icons on partitions, indicating issues? And right click to see issue? Post parted output.

out of parted -l

campture gparted

In the second screenshot the NVME is shown but the partitions are not visible but in the output of the parted -l command all partitions are shown correctly

Did you install ISO to NVMe drive? That often totally erases partition table. Live installer ISO is intended to be installed to smaller flash drive to be used for installing.Try this: sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 You may have backup gpt table from end of drive.

capture of command gdisk -l

Better to just copy & paste output of commands in question above. Some do not like to click on unknown sites. Gdisk looks ok, other than you have two ESP - efi system partitions. Some systems do not like more than one ESP per drive. Try removing boot,esp flags from second FAT32 partition. Do you have UEFI Secure boot on. Make sure it is off.

Of course I have UEFI SECURE BOOT disabled, I will try what you told me about ESP.
